# Easy way to simulate a console prompt in a text game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to obtain an effect that simulate a console, so the player can interact with it for fun.

I did place an image to use as background, and a text game object on top, which cover a good amount of the image. I can type the text and update the text, but it won't really look like if it has been typed (the cursor won't blink, the text appear immediately as soon as I change the .text value).

Is there an easy way to simulate the typing and the cursor blinking? I am using C# to achieve this.

I am trying to add a loop, where each 500 millisecond, I type a character and refresh the string, so in the update function, it should look like if the text is written character by character.

The problem is that from what I recall, update function goes at its own pace; so it means that it would print each line at the same speed; which won't look like if the text was typed.

Any suggestion about how to influence the update function? (beside using coroutine)

Comment: What's wrong with using coroutines when it'll be less cumbersome than running in the update loop? You probably want some variability in the delay on typing a character, maybe have a lookup-table of common typos (eg: 'N' key is next to 'M') which you can sprinkle in randomly.

Comment: Coroutine is fine, so far is the only way that I found to do it. I do generate a random value for the yield, so there is a bit of variance in the typing speed. So this is the best solution to achieve this kind of effect?

Comment: you could also use `InvokeRepeating("YourFunction", 1.0f)` but you wouldn't be able to use variance in this case.

Comment: If you really really want to go with update you could introduce the `float timeTilNextChar;` or something. Then in the `Update` loop subtract `Time.deltaTime` from it, if it goes below 0 then type the next char and reassign random float to `timeTilNextChar` but this is more tedious than Coroutines, i think.

Comment: Agree; it seems that coroutines are the best way to add variations and it is fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I came up with, to solve the issue.

Coroutines are the simpliest way to implement this effect; if you have a different way, I would be happy to look at your solution.

in the start function, create either a list of strings, or a simple array of strings (I use an array since I do not modify the array; save space with immutable datatypes). This will be what you print on the screen as if you would type it.

IF you want to simulate a terminal; you can also add replies to the commands that you type; which complicate a bit the function, but not that much.

```
void Start()
{

    string typed_commands[] = new string[]{
        "ls\n",
        "cat\n",
        "cp\n"
    };

    StartCoroutine("FakeTerminal");
}

IEnumerator FakeTerminal()
{
    float delaytime = 0.3f;
    string prompt - ">: ";

    foreach (string text_command in typed_commands)
    {
        output_text += prompt;
        foreach (char character in text_command)
        {
            if (character == '\n')
            {            
                output_text += "Whatever you want to print as reply";
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            }
            delaytime = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.1f, 0.3f);
            output_text += character;
            textfield.text = output_text;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delaytime);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the random give you a variance between 0.1 and 0.3, which create a suddle variation in typing speed, making it more believable as typed.

I did use '\n' to know when a new sentence is starting; and this can simulate the response from the terminal, if you need one; otherwise it will simply wait for a bit, before the next command is typed. 
This is the simpliest way that I found to actually get a sequence of commands to be typed on screen, as if it was a terminal. Far from perfect but better than nothing.